# How does the Python subsequence operator bypass indexing errors?

Tags: python, string

Ok so I'm going through a [Udacity](http://www.udacity.com) course and am stuck at trying to figure out this particular quirk with Python string manipulation.

Given this scenario,

```
 1     x = ''    
 2     print x[0]
```

I would get an "index out of range" error at line 2, as I should, because there is no 0th position in the empty string.

But in *this* scenario,

```
 1     x = ''    
 2     print x[0:]
```

there would be no indexing error, whatsoever. **Why is this**? How is it that the subsequence operator can bypass indexing errors that should seemingly be there?

Thanks for your help in advance!

---

In case I wasn't clear, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AFYigYIunQ4&feature=player_embedded) is a link to an 80 second solution to the problem I'm talking about (with a less than satisfactory explanation to my current question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x[0]` is expected to return a single element, which can even be `None`. (for example, `[None][0] == None` ) So when there is nothing at index 0, what can it return? It can't return anything - it can't even return `None`, as it would be ambiguous with `None` ACTUALLY being at that index. It has to raise an exception.

`x[0:]` on the other hand, returns a list containing 0 or more elements, so it can return 'I found nothing' by returning an empty list. (Note that `x[0:]` isn't implemented through calling `x[0]` `x[1]` etc, but using different underlying code.)

Comment: That makes sense! Didn't know that last bit about the underlying code. Thanks!

Comment: As a follow up, does x[0:] simply not care that the requested starting point doesn't exist?

Comment: @nati22 Indeed it does not care. It can validly return 'there are no elements in the slice starting at index 0 and continuing upwards' as an empty list, so it does. According to the python website: "Degenerate slice indices are handled gracefully: an index that is too large is replaced by the string size, an upper bound smaller than the lower bound returns an empty string. Out-of-range negative slice indices are truncated, but don’t try this for single-element (non-slice) indices."